# Select from in multi-tables and multi-database

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to do something like:

```
SELECT    data, hour, user, 
FROM         [dbx].dbo._datamodel AS db0
UNION
SELECT    data, hour, user, 
FROM         [dby].dbo._datamodel AS db1
UNION
SELECT    data, hour, user, 
FROM         [dbz].dbo._datamodel AS db02
UNION
...
```

We have to do it for a lot of DDBB and we are looking the way to do it automatically for each DB with a condition.
We don't want to add the `UNION` and select for each DB every time.

Any one have an advice or idea how to do it?

Comment: create a procedure with a parameter db_name run it as many times as you want with giving the db name you need

Comment: What you mean by _DDBB_??

Comment: Hi, DDBB means DataBase,

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for DynamicSQL

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT data, hour, user FROM ';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + [name] + '.dbo._datamodel UNION SELECT * FROM '
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE dbid > 4 ; --ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB  with dbid 5 and 6
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 21);
SELECT @SQL;
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a view in a standard database that has the `union`:

```
create view v_datamodel as
    select . . .
    union
    . . .;
```

(Side note:  If you really just want `union all`, then use it.  `union` incurs lots of extra overhead.)

If your set of databases is fixed, then you can create the view once -- set it and forget it.

If databases are being added and removed, then you have a process for doing so.  This process can update the view, perhaps by using dynamic SQL as suggested in another answer.  Or, you might have the list of appropriate databases somewhere other than `sysdatabases`.

If the database are created "ad hoc", then you could use DDL triggers.  I'm not sure if you can define these on `create database`, but within each database, you could check for the creation of the "data model" table.